# Ignite Vs Redis Websession Clustering

Tags: spring, session, redis, ignite

I have a web application that does real time transaction processing and we are trying to implement an external session manager with Redis or Ignite.

Ours is a Spring based application so that bought us to this choice b/w Redis and Ignite(hazelcast SSl and all is not free anymore so skipping it).

Spring by default gives filters for session management on Redis and Ignite has filters that i can hook in in web.xml.

> https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/web-session-clustering

Since it is a hook up in web.xml i am leaning more towards Ignite,as i am no more totally tied to spring. However we are concerned on the limited documentation Ignite has.

For all those experts out there what would be your first choice?. Is Ignite suitable for a long running solution?.

Is there any other reason why i should move away from Ignite?.

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite is definitely a mature product and will be able to fully support your use case. Documentation is not very large indeed, but that's more because the configuration for session clustering is pretty straightforward.

Disclaimer: I'm an Apache Ignite committer, so know much more about Ignite than about Redis. I'm not trying to compare these two products here.